# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2020 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 3):

I would like everyone to think about applying as a moderator on Freelancing.SE. The job is not too painful, and there is a large group of helpful moderators that are willing to offer guidance and advice. Currently, we have two moderators - myself and [JohnHC♦](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users/15202/johnhc).

This is the second time we have done an election, and barely anyone stepped forward. I want to assure you this is a fun thing to participate in, and we are a small enough site that you won't get burned out from moderating. As Moderators, we are "Human Exception Handlers" - we only handle issues the community cannot. For the most part, most spam is caught either by the automated systems, or by users flagging the content for removal (and the system removes it).

Please head over to the Election page (linked above), and give it a try. I could use some other folks to lean on :)

Answer (score 2):

The nominations for the election have been extended for another week as we need more candidates.

Please check the [other answer here](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/316/21816) and consider nominating in the [election page](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/election/2)!