# 2020 Community Moderator Election - Failed Election

Tags: discussion, election

After [extending the nomination period](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/317/21816) for another week but still not finding any candidates, we've had to cancel the election this time and consider it a failed election.

The next steps are for the Community to consider here what may have gone wrong, if we can have more interest on a new one, and if so, when can we host a new one.

We usually wait a month between elections and trying again, however, being that we have many elections to run across the network, it's likely the next when we can run one is January - but we will try to expedite it being that Freelancing needs more moderators.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's unclear to the users of this not terribly active community how (or whether) moderation would improve it.

Comment: How could SE or myself show that we need moderation for the site to continue to run smoothly?

Comment: Demonstrate what the problems or issues are

Comment: I would expect that most users of this site also use other SE sites and would therefore be familiar with their moderation.  Those who use only this site may not have the rep to stand.

Comment: My problem right now is burn out - I'm the only active moderator on this site, and have been since inception. Yes, I want to continue to serve the community, but I need help so that it does not feel like a job.

Comment: Understandable; no fun being The Lone Ranger. I have never been a moderator here or elsewhere and have no idea whether I would even qualify reputation-wise.

Comment: @morsor There is no reputation requirement. If you think you can be the Human Exception Handler, and deal with spammy users/flags, and help set the direction for the community, then I invite you to put your name forward when the nominations open again.

Comment: OK. I'll consider it at the very least

Comment: Well, at an absolute minimum, the lack of an active moderation team will result in the site being shuttered entirely.